# how to change delete icon in jqgrid toolbar and in actions column

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I tried to replace jqgrid default delete icon in toolbar and in actions column with minus sign using

```
        $.extend($.jgrid.del, {
            delicon: 'ui-icon-minusthick'
}
);
```

but default icon (trash is still shown). How to replace it with minus sign ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
$.extend($.jgrid.nav, {delicon: "ui-icon-minusthick"});
```

to change "Delete" icon of the navigator.

To change "Delete" icon of the formatter "actions" you have to do something like the following

```
loadComplete: function () {
    $(this).find("div.ui-inline-del>span")
        .removeClass("ui-icon-trash")
        .addClass("ui-icon-minusthick");
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomDelIcon.htm):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
$('.ui-icon-trash').removeClass('ui-icon-trash').addClass('ui-icon-minusthick');
```